# Activate Popover on Hover and click anywhere to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, popover

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and wanted to use the popover where I can hover to active and close it when you click anywhere.

I also want to make the link work inside the popover. Anyone have any idea how to make it work or what am I missing?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        trigger : 'hover',
        html : true
    });
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    //only buttons
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a href="mailto:test@test.com" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover" data-content="test content <a href='' title='test add link'>link on content</a>" data-original-title="test title">Test</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rendering the link, use `html: true` and to show/hide the popover, you can use the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    placement: 'top',
    html: true
  });

  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).popover('show');
  });
  
  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function() {
      if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $(this).popover('hide');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html, body{ height: 100%; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<a href="mailto:test@test.com" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover" data-content="test content <a href='#' title='test add link'>link on content</a>" data-original-title="test title">Test</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks Anurag.

Comment: Yeh, thats nice

Answer (score 1):

Please add `html: true` in your popover so, It can render HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        trigger : 'hover',
        html: true
    });
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    //only buttons
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
    //buttons and icons within buttons
    /*
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('[data-toggle="popover"]').length === 0
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
    */
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a href="mailto:test@test.com" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover" data-content="test content <a href='' title='test add link'>link on content</a>" data-original-title="test title">Test</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you know a way to make the popover stay on hover?

Comment: Already it is stuck in hover, what you want, I don't understand correctly

Comment: When you hover, popover stays active. because right now, when you stop hovering, the popover will disappear.

Comment: so what you want? on hover, on click or stay till you close it?

Comment: Yes, I want the popover to stay. It will only close if you click anywhere else.